# ReferenceError: msg is not defined + "Parsing error : 'return' outside of function

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm trying to create a purge command following a basic tutorial where the command is put in server.js, I'm not sure if the tutorial is up-to-date but I get some error in my code.

Here is my code:

```js
const Discord = require("discord.js");
const bot = require("./handler/ClientBuilder.js");
const Client = new bot();

require("./handler/module.js")(Client);
require("./handler/Event.js")(Client);

Client.package = require("./package.json");
Client.on("warn", console.warn); // Cette ligne permet de vous avertir via les logs si quelque chose se passe mal avec votre bot.
Client.on("error", console.error); // Cette ligne vous permet de recevoir un message d'erreur via les logs si quelque chose est manquant dans votre code.
Client.login(process.env.SECRET).catch(console.error); // Ce token vous dirigera vers le  fichier .env. Il est en sÃ©curitÃ© ici.


if (msg.startsWith(prefix + "prune") || msg.startsWith(prefix + "purge")) { // You can make an aliases. Just like that.
    if (!message.member.hasPermission("MANAGE_MESSAGES") || !message.member.hasPermission("ADMINISTRATOR")) return message.channel.send("Vous n'avez pas les permissions requises pour effectuer cette action.")
    if (isNaN(args[0])) return message.channel.send("Veuillez écrire un nombre.") // isNaN = is Not a Number. (case  sensitive, write it right)
    if (args[0] > 100) return message.channel.send("Veuillez écrire un nombre inférieur Ã  100.") // Discord Limited purge number into 100.
    if (args[0] <= 2) return message.channel.send("Veuillez écrire un nombre supérieur Ã  1.")

    message.delete()
    message.channel.bulkDelete(args[0])
        .then(messages => message.channel.send(`Deleted ${message.size}/${args[0]} messages.`)).then(d => d.delete({
            timeout: 10000
        })) // How long this message will be deleted. in ms.
        .catch(() => message.channel.send("Quelque chose c'est mal passÃ©, lors de la tentative de suppression des messages.")) // This error will be displayed when the bot doesn't have an access to do it.

}
```

So this is the content of my server.js.

These are the 2 errors that give me a hard time:

```
line 14 : "Parsing error : 'return' outside of function.
```

```
/app/server.js:14
if (msg.startsWith(prefix + "prune") || msg.startsWith(prefix + "purge")) { // You can make an aliases. Just like that.
^
ReferenceError: msg is not defined
at Object.<anonymous> (/app/server.js:14:1)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:759:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:770:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:628:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:555:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:826:10)
    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:11
```

I've followed another tutorial for setting up my bot with a command /event handler. So here's a screenshot of what it looks like:

[structure tree of my discord bot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IADXc.png)

Maybe I put the command in the wrong place, and shouldn't belong in server.js. I try to put it in my events/message.js, I get no error in the console and the bot goes online well, but the command simply doesn't work.

Comment: Java != JavaScript

Comment: "Java is to Javascript what Car is to Carpet" (cit.)

Comment: ReferenceError is because `msg` var is not found in the file. Second is a valid syntax error that you cannot use `return` outside a function.